# How to Insert text of a webpage in blogger?

Tags: reference, blogger

I want to add "tags" or reference info to my blogs posts. For example: "insects-4 wings".

I'll use that same reference in many posts, so... what i want to achieve (if it's possible) is that if i want to change that reference to "Insects with more than 2 wings", i don't have to change it in all the post that have it.

So my "idea" is creating a webpage with a text with that reference and make it appear on the posts through some kind of link to the webpage, so when i want to change the reference i just have to modify the webpages text.

If there are easier ways to achieve this, they are welcome of course.

Comment: A very simple way to achieve this is to create one image with the reference and change that image, but there isn't a text option to achieve exactly the same in a more simple way?